# Issue formatting a multiplication table in Python using nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I've gotten everything formatted correctly, except for the top labels for the columns and the underline that goes underneath the column labels. I suspect the first for loop is incorrectly coded, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
def main():

    print("This is a times-table.")

    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(" {:3d}".format(i), end='')
    print()

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, " |{:3d}".format(i), end='')
        for x in range(1, n+1):
            print("{:3d}".format(i*x), end="")

        print()

main()
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueQSc.jpg)

Comment: Output? Desired output?

Comment: I added a photo of the desired output to the post.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def main():

    print("This is a times-table.")

    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(" {:3d}".format(i), end='')
    print()

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, " |{:3d}".format(i), end='')
        for x in range(2, n+1):
            print("{:3d}".format(i*x), end="")

        print()

main()
```

It was in the `x` for loop, where you needed to start from 2. This is because, in the for loop above it, you already set the first number by stating `|{:3d}`. You could either remove that, or start from 2.

Furthermore, you probably want to improve on this by setting the numbers above the columns on the right spot.
I'll give you a headstart by giving you a working solution for the tables up to 9.

```py
def main():

    print("This is a times-table.")

    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    
    print("   |",end="")
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print("{:3d}".format(i), end='')
    print()
    print("---+-"+"---"*n)

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, " |{:3d}".format(i), end='')
        for x in range(2, n+1):
            print("{:3d}".format(i*x), end="")

        print()

main()
```

Now for you is the question, how to continue when multiplications exceed 2 digits.

Comment: Changing it to 2 didn't change the output for me. It didn't move the top row at all :/

Comment: That's true, that involves some calculations on how much space you need for your number, i.e. calculate the width by taking the size of the number that takes the most digits in said column.

Comment: Trying to set the numbers above the columns is what I am having trouble with. I've tried changing the size of the width a dozen different ways and it's still not working.

Comment: Well, in order to know how much space you need, you need to know how many digits occur in that column. For instance, the tables up to 9 do not have more than 3 digits. The plan here is, to figure out how many digits you need, and then print the amount of '-' or ' ' you need respectively. Try that first.

Answer (score 0):

for row in range(0, 10):
for col in range(0, 10):
num = row * col
if num < 10:
empty = "  "
else:
if num < 100:
empty = " "
if col == 0:
if row == 0:
print("    ", end='')
else:
print("  ", row, end='')
elif row == 0:
print("  ", col, end='')
else:
print(empty, num, end='')
print()

Comment: Please correctly format your code and add some explanation as to how this answers the question